# CNN image to image regression output has very high loss 99.3%

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a deep learning model that takes 4d image as input and predicts 1D image. But my loss is very high. Could anyone help me find out why.

sample input images:
[1st dimension[][1]][1]+[2nd dimension][2]+[3rd dimension][3]+[4th dimension][4]==== output [desired output image][5]

information contain output image is very less.

I used RMSE for loss calculation form tf.keras. it seems to be not converging.

Here is how my loss looks like:

Epoch 1/5
25/27 [==========================>...] - ETA: 1:16 - loss: 99.7717 - acc: 0.0000e+00

Model architecture and model fitting code is as follows:

```
def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (512,512,4)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(inputs)
    #conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    #conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    #conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
    #conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
    #conv5 = Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = Conv2DTranspose(512, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(drop5)
    #merge6 = concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)
    merge6=up6
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
    #conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 =Conv2DTranspose(256, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(conv6)
    #merge7 = concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)
    merge7=up7
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
    #conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)

    #up8 = Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(Conv2DTranspose(1, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(conv7))
    up8 = Conv2DTranspose(128, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(conv7)
    #merge8 = concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
    merge8=up8
    Conv2DTranspose(1, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    #conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)

    #up9 = Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(Conv2DTranspose(1, (3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(conv8))
    up9 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(conv8)
    #merge9 = concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
    merge9=up9
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    #conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    #conv9 = Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)
    conv11 = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((512, 512))(conv10)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs,conv11)
    
    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    
    #model.summary()

    if(pretrained_weights):
        model.load_weights(pretrained_weights)

    return model

model=unet()
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsolutePercentageError(),optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(), metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_ds,epochs=5,verbose=1,validation_data=validation_ds)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9x3C.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LjZ4.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu0cm.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiKlg.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0izQ.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can perform few of the following checks to figure out the problem:

- Check if target image is being loaded correctly
- Change optimizer and play around with learning rate
- Train for few more epochs to see if loss is converging
- Sometimes the loss function has poor convergence. I see that you are using mean_absolute_percentage_error. It is not a smooth loss function and likely to have convergence issues. May be train model using rmse for few epochs and then switch out

Comment: My input size is (987x512x512x4).(samplesize x image width x image hight x demension )  and output size is (987x512x512). I change optimizer to adam and play around with data. but network seems to be converging over to hte value zero.(image with value zero every where in 512x512).  however my output(expected image is also contain 90% of zeros per one image). i wonder if that will also effect for the convergence

Comment: i cound't find any image to image mapping CNN code. still im tring to find one which has used python and tensorflow.

Comment: Hi Kasun! did u try changing loss function, it might help to use mse(mean squared error)